# Can you have two webViews running at the same time in the same activity in Android?

Tags: android, android-webview, webchromeclient

I created a simple activity that contains two webViews side by side. I use the following code to initiate them.

```
setContentView(R.layout.detail); //xml layout that contains two webviews

webView1 = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView1);
webView2 = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView2);

webView1.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
webView1.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");


webView2.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
webView2.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
```

The problem is that with the above code webView1 loads fine while webView2 is always blank (just a white box) and I do not understand why.

Here is my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="10dip"
android:paddingLeft="10dip"
android:paddingRight="10dip"
android:paddingTop="10dip" >


    <WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView2"
    android:layout_width="470dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

    <WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="470dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="49dp"
        android:text="Cell"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="Name"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/TextView01"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="23dp"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: aren't they on top of each other ? how large is your screen ?

Comment: No its a nexus 7, they are side by side, screen width is greater than 1000dp.

Comment: what happens if you don't load the url in webView1 ?

Comment: What type of ViewGroup are your two WebViews in?

Comment: No change, I am starting to wonder if this is just an issue with eclipse, with my xml file.

Comment: Updated to show full layout file.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem was actually with eclipse because after completely removing webView1 I received this error:

```
android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.webkit.WebView
```

Which you can see from my code makes no sense considering you can see I am not doing that anywhere and am actually not even using the TextViews yet.

A full clean and odd issues still exist. I am going to move to Android Studio.

- Moved to Android Studio and all is working as expected and dealing with layouts is much faster than my experience with eclipse.